# AspectJ "declare error" not catching method as expected. Why?

Tags: java, aspectj

I defined a `Point` class:

```
public class Point {
    ...
    public String toString() {
        return "abc";
    }
}
```

as well as an aspect that should take care that no one overrides its `toString()` method:

```
declare error
    : execution(public String Point+.toString()) && !execution(public String Point.toString()) 
    : "Forbidden execution operation!";

declare error
    : call(public String Point+.toString()) && !call(public String Point.toString()) 
    : "Forbidden call operation!";
```

Yet, when typing the following code, there is no error flagged whatsoever:

```
class Point4 extends Point {
    public Point4(int x, int y) {
        super(x, y);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() { //I'd be expecing a compilation error here.
        return super.toString();
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Point4 p = new Point4(2, 3);
        System.out.println(p.toString()); //I'd be expecting a compilation error here
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This declare error will catch all declarations of the invalid `toString` methods:

```
declare error
: !within(Point) && execution(public String Point.toString()) 
: "Forbidden call operation!";
```

This gets you half of the way there.  The other piece is to use this:

```
declare error
: call(public String (Point+ && !Point).toString())
: "Forbidden call operation";
```

I'm not exactly sure why your variant of this declaration isn't working, but the pointcut above is shorter, more explicit and recommended (and most importantly...works correctly).